# SVN Checkout not working in Ansible

Tags: svn, ansible

While executing the ansible playbook for svn checkout in my server, the below error is throwing out.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "ERROR: /var/www/html/svn/ folder already exists, but its not a subversion repository."}<br/>
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/svn.retry<br/>
```

My Playbook code is,

```
---
-
  hosts: localhost
  name: "Checkout from SVN"
  tasks:
    -
      subversion: "repo=svn+ssh://source.mysite.net/svn/TMRep/source/ dest=/var/www/html/svn/ username=username password=password"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it:

> ERROR: /var/www/html/svn/ folder already exists, but its not a subversion repository

If you doesn't care about content, try subversion with `export=yes`:

> `export` – If `yes`, do export instead of checkout/update.

Comment: you are asking to change my code like this..? subversion: "repo=svn+ssh://source.mysite.net/svn/TMRep/source/ dest=/var/www/html/svn/ username=username password=password export=yes"

Comment: yes. try it first before running in production if you unsure.

Comment: this one worked for me..Thanks Konstantin..! subversion: "repo=http://source.mysite.net/svn/TMRep/source/ dest=/var/www/html/svn/ username=username password=password force=yes export=yes"